# Location allocation Road Block- Unable to "Solve"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, network-analyst, location-allocation

Software: ArcGIS/ArcMap 10.3.1 with network analyst extension
Objective: Perform location-allocation services, based off of two Required Facilities and Demand Points.

I feel like I have all critical pieces I need:

- State Shapefile, created a network dataset via it (most recent from here: http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america/us/florida.html)
- Facilities Locations - Created a Shapefile (Through ArcCatalog .xls to shapefile) Properties changed to make them Required Facilities, Respective Facility capacities entered
- Demand Points - Created a shapefile (through ArcCatalog .xls to shapefile)
- Location Allocation- Accepts my network dataset, impedance cut-off at 120, Facilities to choose at 2, Problem type changed to Maximize Coverage, and Travel Point selected "Demand to Facility".

However, I believe I have a layer connectivity issue. I say this because when I attempt to "Solve" my analysis. No lines are rendered. I've tried countless different file types/sources (shape, osm, pbf, bz2), as well as trying to allow ArcMap Geocode my addresses, importing my LAT/LONG with their X/Y fields, with no avail.

Everything on my map, looks great in terms of the roads, where the facilities and demand points get plotted. However, when attempting to "Solve" my analysis... no lines are drawn.

Does anybody have suggestions of what I could possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest investigating the network dataset first. Is it built? Try to add the nd into ArcMap, create a Route layer, and two stops and run Solve. You should get a route line drawn (provided the stops are within the searching tolerance).

Comment: What happened when you tried the suggestion of @AlexTereshenkov?

Comment: 120 of what units; meters, miles, kilometers, seconds? Is there any demand point within 120 (of any unit you have choosen)? Have you tried to solve your problem with higher impedance? Is your network consistent enough?